# Convert new lines to blanks within blocks of text separated by empty lines

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file as below.
A block of data starts with zone and after a block of lines there is always a horizontal white space, a blank line.

#### foo.txt

```
zone name Z_ZEBRA_TIGER vsan 900
* fcid 0x801e00 [device-alias TEST]
* fcid 0x3d8b40 [device-alias TIGER1]
* fcid 0x3d8bc0 [device-alias TIGER2]
* fcid 0x3d8b60 [device-alias CAT]

zone name Z_chili_yahoo vsan 100
* fcid 0x801400 [device-alias chilli]
* fcid 0x803500 [device-alias yahoo]

zone name Z_tom_tommy vsan 100
* fcid 0x801400 [device-alias toma]
  pwwn 0x803460 [device-alias tommya]
```

I want to print it as below — starting from zone word till the blank line convert the line to print side by side.

```
zone name Z_ZEBRA_TIGER vsan 900  * fcid 0x801e00 [device-alias TEST]  * fcid 0x3d8b40 [device-alias TIGER1]  * fcid 0x3d8bc0 [device-alias TIGER2]  * fcid 0x3d8b60 [device-alias CAT]
zone name Z_chili_yahoo vsan 100  * fcid 0x801400 [device-alias chilli]  * fcid 0x803500 [device-alias yahoo]
zone name Z_tom_tommy vsan 100  * fcid 0x801400 [device-alias toma]    pwwn 0x803460 [device-alias tommya]
```

I tried using tr, no luck. Can anybody help please?
Any easy way to achieve this via sed or awk.

Answer (score 6):

### Using awk

```
$ awk -v RS="" -F'\n' -v OFS=" " '{$1=$1;print}' foo.txt
zone name Z_ZEBRA_TIGER vsan 900 * fcid 0x801e00 [device-alias TEST] * fcid 0x3d8b40 [device-alias TIGER1] * fcid 0x3d8bc0 [device-alias TIGER2] * fcid 0x3d8b60 [device-alias CAT]
zone name Z_chili_yahoo vsan 100 * fcid 0x801400 [device-alias chilli] * fcid 0x803500 [device-alias yahoo]
zone name Z_tom_tommy vsan 100 * fcid 0x801400 [device-alias toma]   pwwn 0x803460 [device-alias tommya]
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS=""`

  Use a blank line as the record separator.
- `-F'\n'`

  Use a newline as the field separator on input.
- `-v OFS=" "`

  Use a space as the field separator on output.
- `$1=$1`

  This sets the first field equal to itself.  This has the effect of signaling that the line has been changed and this will cause awk to replace the old field separators with the new ones upon output.
- `print`

  Print the record.

#### Short form

As Jotne points out, it is possible to make a shorter form.  First, because the output field separator is, by default, a space, we don't need to set it explicitly.  Secondly, it is possible to use an implicit `print`.  Thus, the above command is functionally equivalent to:

```
awk -v RS="" -F'\n' '{$1=$1}1' foo.txt
```

### Using sed

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/\n/ /g; s/ zone name/\nzone name/g' foo.txt
zone name Z_ZEBRA_TIGER vsan 900 * fcid 0x801e00 [device-alias TEST] * fcid 0x3d8b40 [device-alias TIGER1] * fcid 0x3d8bc0 [device-alias TIGER2] * fcid 0x3d8b60 [device-alias CAT] 
zone name Z_chili_yahoo vsan 100 * fcid 0x801400 [device-alias chilli] * fcid 0x803500 [device-alias yahoo] 
zone name Z_tom_tommy vsan 100 * fcid 0x801400 [device-alias toma]   pwwn 0x803460 [device-alias tommya]
```

This reads the whole file in at once.  If the input file is huge (too big for memory), use the awk solution.

#### How it works

- `:a;N;$!ba;`

  This reads the whole file in at once.
- `s/\n/ /g;`

  This replaces all newlines with spaces.
- `s/ zone name/\nzone name/g`

  This puts a newline in front of any occurrence of the phrase `zone name`.

Comment: Nice explanation.  The `$1=$1` is particularly subtle.

Comment: `OFS` is default one space, so can be omitted: `awk -v RS="" -F'\n' '{$1=$1}1'  file`

Comment: assuming that there is no (like in sample, and seems not so OK) `zone name` as alias device

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^$/!{H;$!b
             }
        s/.*//;x;s/.//;s/\n/ /g;p' YourFile
```

with sed.

- `-n`: print only on demand
- `/^$/!`: if not a *white line*

  - `H`: append line to buffer.
  - `$!b`  If not the end of file (last line), treat cycle the script (restart with next line)
- `s/.*//;x`; empty the current line and swap it with the buffer
- `s/.//;s/\n/ /g`: remove first char (a new line from first append) and change all new line to a space
- `p`: print the result and cycle to next line

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
perl -00 -nE 's/\n/ /g; say' foo.txt
```

- `-00` reads the file a paragraph at a time